# Silverlight Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: .net, silverlight, serialization, deserialization

I am working on a dental practice web application, in which I need to develop patient chart where doctor can mark treatment on tooth. This should be graphical presentation where doctor can right click on tooth and select treatment and it will change / modify tooth image to show treatment.

My application is built in `ASP.NET C#` and `MSSQL`. For Patient charting, I am using `Silverlight 4`. I have got success to draw canvas with images and applying context menu on same. But now I have to serialize / save canvas to database or in a file, so in future doctor can open canvas and continue more treatment.

So now can you please advise me on how to serialize / deserialize a canvas?

Comment: What have you looked at already?

Comment: A canvas is a UI object. Don't serialize UI objects, instead serialize the data that is represented on a UI. You then deserialize data and represent it on a UI. This means your data is separate from your representation, which is a good thing.

Comment: Do you use a model that represents each tooth (see [dental notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_notation))? The position won't change between sessions, only the treatment information has to be saved for each tooth.